# omniORB C++ server, Java client problems with running application

Tags: c++, java, corba, omniorb

I have problem with running my application. I have a server:

```
#include "Hello_impl.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <omniORB4/CORBA.h>
#include <omniORB4/Naming.hh>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
try {
// init ORB
CORBA::ORB_ptr orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);

// init POA
CORBA::Object_var poa_obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");
PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow(poa_obj);
PortableServer::POAManager_var manager = poa->the_POAManager();

// create service
Hello_impl * service = new Hello_impl;

// register within the naming service
try {
CORBA::Object_var ns_obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");
if (!CORBA::is_nil(ns_obj)) {
CosNaming::NamingContext_ptr nc = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(ns_obj);
CosNaming::Name name;
name.length(1);
name[0].id = CORBA::string_dup("TestServer");
name[0].kind = CORBA::string_dup("");
nc->rebind(name, service->_this());
cout << "Server is running ..." << endl;
}
} catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound &) {
cerr << "not found" << endl;
} catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::InvalidName &) {
cerr << "invalid name" << endl;
} catch (CosNaming::NamingContext::CannotProceed &) {
cerr << "cannot proceed" << endl;
}

// run
manager->activate();
orb->run();

// clean up
delete service;

// quit
orb->destroy();
} catch (CORBA::UNKNOWN) {
cerr << "unknown exception" << endl;
} catch (CORBA::SystemException &) {
cerr << "system exception" << endl;
}
}
```

and a Client:

```
import java.util.*;

public class client {
public static void main(String [] args) {
org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, null);
if (orb == null) System.exit(-1);
try {
// obtain service from naming server
org.omg.CORBA.Object ns_obj = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContext nc
= org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(ns_obj);
org.omg.CosNaming.NameComponent [] path
= { new org.omg.CosNaming.NameComponent("TestServer", "") };
org.omg.CORBA.Object obj = nc.resolve(path);
Hello hello = HelloHelper.narrow(obj);

// use service
String server = hello.say_hello("Hello, omniORB C++ server, it's Java client");
System.out.println("Answer from server: " + server);

// destroy
orb.destroy();
} catch (org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage.InvalidName exception) {
exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
} catch (org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound exception) {
exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
} catch (org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.CannotProceed exception) {
exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
} catch (org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName exception) {
exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
} catch (org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE exception) {
exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
} catch (Exception exception) {
exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
}
}
```

I start omniNames like this:

```
omniNames -start 6666 -logdir /home/mazix/Desktop/example/logs -errlog /home/mazix/Desktop/example/logs/omniNamesError.txt
```

then, i start my server, like this:

```
./server -ORBInitRef NameService=IOR: .... (and here is my IOR num)
```

and I start client (on the same computer) : like this:

```
java client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameService
```

And its working but I would like to (need to) start my server like this:

```
./server NameService=corbaname::localhost:6666
```

and clinet:

```
java client -ORBInitialHost localhost -ORBInitialPort 6666
```

but its not working when I start it like that:/

Any help? :(

Here's my omniORB configuration file: http://www.2shared.com/document/dBAhFGLh/omniORB4cfg.html

Beside that, I have troubles, when server is on my computer, while client is on the computer in my school. They "don't see" each other :(

---

Ok, I know: I didn't start my omniNames but something was listening on port 2809 before I started omniNames, I checked it, and its:  http://i47.tinypic.com/2d2ha9u.png

I thought its all right and I dont need to run omniNames by typing in terminal "omniNames" and didnt do it

I only tried to run my server like You said: http://i46.tinypic.com/2q2e33c.png

---

I tried this:

1. Ran my omniNames: omniNames -start 6666
2. Ran my server: ./server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameService -ORBtraceLevel 40

and got this:

```
mazix@computer:~/Desktop/example/cpp$ ./server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameServie -ORBtraceLevel 40
omniORB: Read from configuration file "/etc/omniORB.cfg".
omniORB: Version: 4.1.2
omniORB: Distribution date: Thu Feb 14 14:19:08 GMT 2008 dgrisby
omniORB: My addresses are: 
omniORB: 127.0.0.1
omniORB: 10.0.2.15
omniORB: ::1
omniORB: Maximum supported GIOP version is 1.2
omniORB: Native char code sets: ISO-8859-1 UTF-8.
omniORB: Transmission char code sets: ISO-8859-1(1.2) ISO-8859-1(1.1) ISO-8859-1(1.0) UTF-8(1.2) UTF-8(1.1).
omniORB: Native wide char code sets: UTF-16.
omniORB: Transmission wide char code sets: UTF-16(1.2).
omniORB: Information: the omniDynamic library is not linked.
omniORB: Creating ref to remote: key<INIT>
 target id      : omg.org/CORBA/InitialReferences:1.0
 most derived id: omg.org/CORBA/InitialReferences:1.0
omniORB: Current configuration is as follows:
omniORB:   DefaultInitRef (file) = corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameService
omniORB:   DefaultInitRef (args) = 
omniORB:   InitRef = NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameServie
omniORB:   abortOnInternalError = 0
omniORB:   abortOnNativeException = 0
omniORB:   acceptBiDirectionalGIOP = 0
omniORB:   acceptMisalignedTcIndirections = 0
omniORB:   bootstrapAgentHostname = localhost
omniORB:   bootstrapAgentPort = 900
omniORB:   clientCallTimeOutPeriod = 0
omniORB:   clientConnectTimeOutPeriod = 0
omniORB:   clientTransportRule = * unix,ssl,tcp
omniORB:   configFile = /etc/omniORB.cfg
omniORB:   connectionWatchImmediate = 0
omniORB:   connectionWatchPeriod = 50000
omniORB:   copyValuesInLocalCalls = 1
omniORB:   diiThrowsSysExceptions = 0
omniORB:   dumpConfiguration = 0
omniORB:   endPoint = giop:tcp::
omniORB:   endPointPublish = addr
omniORB:   giopMaxMsgSize = 2097152
omniORB:   giopTargetAddressMode = KeyAddr
omniORB:   id = omniORB4
omniORB:   idleThreadTimeout = 10
omniORB:   immediateAddressSwitch = 0
omniORB:   inConScanPeriod = 180
omniORB:   lcdMode = 0
omniORB:   maxGIOPConnectionPerServer = 5
omniORB:   maxGIOPVersion = 1.2
omniORB:   maxInterleavedCallsPerConnection = 5
omniORB:   maxServerThreadPerConnection = 100
omniORB:   maxServerThreadPoolSize = 100
omniORB:   maxSocketRecv = 2147483647
omniORB:   maxSocketSend = 2147483647
omniORB:   nativeCharCodeSet = ISO-8859-1
omniORB:   nativeWCharCodeSet = UTF-16
omniORB:   objectTableSize = 0
omniORB:   offerBiDirectionalGIOP = 0
omniORB:   oneCallPerConnection = 1
omniORB:   outConScanPeriod = 120
omniORB:   poaHoldRequestTimeout = 0
omniORB:   poaUniquePersistentSystemIds = 1
omniORB:   principal = [Null]
omniORB:   resetTimeOutOnRetries = 0
omniORB:   scanGranularity = 5
omniORB:   serverCallTimeOutPeriod = 0
omniORB:   serverTransportRule = * unix,ssl,tcp
omniORB:   socketSendBuffer = -1
omniORB:   strictIIOP = 1
omniORB:   supportBootstrapAgent = 1
omniORB:   supportCurrent = 1
omniORB:   supportPerThreadTimeOut = 0
omniORB:   tcAliasExpand = 0
omniORB:   threadPerConnectionLowerLimit = 9000
omniORB:   threadPerConnectionPolicy = 1
omniORB:   threadPerConnectionUpperLimit = 10000
omniORB:   threadPoolWatchConnection = 1
omniORB:   traceExceptions = 1
omniORB:   traceFile = [stderr]
omniORB:   traceInvocationReturns = 0
omniORB:   traceInvocations = 0
omniORB:   traceLevel = 40
omniORB:   traceThreadId = 0
omniORB:   traceTime = 0
omniORB:   unixTransportDirectory = /tmp/omni-%u
omniORB:   unixTransportPermission =  777
omniORB:   useTypeCodeIndirections = 1
omniORB:   verifyObjectExistsAndType = 1
omniORB: Initialising incoming endpoints.
omniORB: Instantiate endpoint 'giop:tcp::0'
omniORB: Bind to address 0.0.0.0
omniORB: Publish specification: 'addr'
omniORB: Try to publish 'addr' for endpoint giop:tcp:10.0.2.15:44025
omniORB: Publish endpoint 'giop:tcp:10.0.2.15:44025'
omniORB: Starting serving incoming endpoints.
omniORB: Creating ref to remote: key<NameServie>
 target id      : IDL:omg.org/CORBA/Object:1.0
 most derived id: 
omniORB: Initial reference `NameService' resolved from -ORBInitRef argument / ORB registration.
omniORB: Client attempt to connect to giop:tcp:localhost:6666
omniORB: Switch rope to use address giop:tcp:localhost:6666
omniORB: Unable to open new connection: giop:tcp:localhost:6666
omniORB: throw giopStream::CommFailure from giopStream.cc:1148(0,NO,TRANSIENT_ConnectFailed)
omniORB: throw TRANSIENT from omniObjRef.cc:789 (NO,TRANSIENT_ConnectFailed)
system exceptionTRANSIENT_ConnectFailed
omniORB: omniRemoteIdentity deleted.
omniORB: ObjRef() -- deleted.
omniORB: ORB not destroyed; no final clean-up.
```

Comment: Can you be more specific that "its not working"? What is it doing? Can you get a thread dump or debug the client?  BTW: If you don't catch exceptions in main() they are printed to the console anway ;)

Comment: When I start my server: ./server NameService=corbaname::localhost:6666 it says: "System exception" and thats it ..

Comment: So the server won't start. I thought it was the client which failed.

Comment: I can upload my whole project, if it helps ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java client -ORBInitialHost localhost -ORBInitialPort 6666
```

is a ORACLE/SUN special technique to find the local naming service. The more flexible and portable way is to use corbaloc addresses for both, client and server. This is in your case:

```
java client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameService
#and 
./server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameService
```

For both, client and server, you can also parse cmdline arguments to have a "nicer" interface, such as

```
java client localhost:6666
# and
./server localhost:6666
```

In this case you have to exchange calls to the `resolve_initial_references("NameService")` with normal object narrowing or patch the ORB configuration/parameters at runtime. (Example can be provided on request)

If the client/server do not run on the same machine, your have to exchange `localhost` with the ip or public name of the server for both, your NamingService and your server.

Comment: Thank U 4 ur answer, but ... I tried to run my server like u said: ./server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameService and I got this error: "System exception", u can see it on screenshot: http://i49.tinypic.com/2444raa.png and I really dont know what to do ..., here's my whole project: http://www.2shared.com/file/neMOyZ91/corba-example.html

Comment: I build your code, but I ran used my NamingService at port 2809, it  works:  
    cpp$ ./server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService  
    
    Server is running ...

Comment: I suppose your NamingService is not running. (netstat -ptupln)

Comment: add `-ORBtraceLevel 40` to your server's commandline and post the output

Comment: @mazix you might also want to alter your code to get more information without debugging `} catch (CORBA::SystemException &e) {
        cerr << "system exception " << e.NP_minorString() << endl;
    }`

Comment: @mazix do you run server and client on the same host? did you try running the server with `-ORBtraceLevel 40` as additional parameter?

Comment: Yes, on the same host, localhost. I tried this:

Ran my omniNames: omniNames -start 6666
Ran my server: ./server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:6666/NameService -ORBtraceLevel 40
and got this: http://pastebin.com/MT7iiS4U it's strange because I ran omniNames, BEFORE I ran my server

Comment: @mazix: OK, over all you solved the problem by reinstalling the orb.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thank You again. But would You be so nice once again, and tell me what I did wrong, that I couldnt connect my client on computer at school with my server at home? I had an application in Java with sockets, also client/server app, and everything was good... so its not the firewall issue. I ran server on my home computer: ./server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService and then ran client on my school computer (using PuTTy): java client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::ip-of-my-home-computer:2809/NameService but my client didnt see my server.

Comment: you have to make sure that your server AND your NameService are reachable under the public IP as well as they have to announce their service at this IP. When you start your server on localhost and it registers to a localhost NameingService it could use "localhost" as hostname as well. but this won't work from other servers.  Use ORBtraceLevel to find out which IP is used by the server as endpoint, if it's not a public IP, use omniORBs endpoint onfiguration (see omniorb manual)

Answer (score 1):

1. What is localHist?  Do you mean localHost?
2. A CORBA client always needs to be provided either an IOR or a corbaloc string, from what I recall.  Perhaps you can configure this locally, but that is likely going to be client specific.  Your server's bindings should be configurable.
3. Your issues between your home computer and school computer are likely firewall-related.  I'd be supremely surprized if your school IT department were not firewalling unknown inbound traffic.  Connecting to a random machine on their network would fall into this category.

Comment: Ad1. Yes. I meant localhost, I'm sorry Ad2. Ok but client is in Java, on my classes teacher showed us a program in Java with CORBA and the started it like this: java client -ORBInitialHost localhost -ORBInitialPort 6666  (when I have both client and server in Java it's ok, but I have server in C++) I also tried to run my server: ./server NameService=corbaname::localhost:6666 but as I said its only says "system exception" ... Ad3. It's strange, cause when I tried to connect my other program (with sockets) on the same school server with my client at home, everything was perfectly working.